# Customizing LineIndicator of ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am new to `ViewPagerIndicator`. I am using `LineIndicator` along with my `ViewPager`. The default look is tiny blue lines wherever you position them.

However, if I want to, say, change the color and the width and height, **how would I do that?**

**Update**
If you look at the [sample phones](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) shown, the one in the center has red lines at the bottom. The title of the app says "Line / Styled (via layout)". That is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: You'll need to make a custom layout for this. You'll make a LinearLayout with a ViewPager and then whatever Indicator you want to use. (Circles, Lines, etc). Since you're using this library, you'll want to put that namespace into the control as well.

See: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/SampleLinesStyledTheme.java

Comment: I have the library in my bin folder. I need to change its default look :) @JonDouglas

Comment: All the custom height/width will be done in that layout. See: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/res/layout/themed_lines.xml

Comment: And if you can't get past styling there, you could always alter the original library's LinePageIndicator.java and any attributes associated to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to style your LinePageIndicator in your .xml layout file.

EX:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        app:strokeWidth="4dp"
        app:lineWidth="30dp"
        app:unselectedColor="#FF888888"
        app:selectedColor="#FF880000"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Couple more newbie questions: 1. How did you know what attributes to edit ? Were they in some documentation ? 2. Why did you add a new namespace ?

Comment: 1. I looked at the source and samples. You can find the attributes here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator/LinePageIndicator.java

2. Because these attributes will override the default control and therefore need to be set in a different namespace app: